# SQL get leaves of directed acyclic graph

Tags: sql, graph-theory, mysql-8.0

I am quite new to SQL and have a rather basic question. Suppose I'm dealing with the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE nodes (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  parent INTEGER REFERENCES nodes(id)
);
```

If we hold an invariant that says, the parent of a node cannot be equivalent to any of its children, then by definition we will not have any loops in our graph. Now we are left with a disjoint directed acyclic graph.

The two questions I have then are:

1. If we cannot change the structure of the database: What `select` statement would I have to write to efficiently get all of the leaves in my database? I.e. the  ids that don't have any children.
2. If we can change the structure of the tables: What could we change or add to make this `select` statement more efficient?

An example of output for the graph with five nodes whose parents where 3->2, 2->1, and 5->4 would output 3 and 5 because they are the only nodes that don't have children.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: assume 8.0 is ok

Comment: this reads a lot like a homework assignment.

Answer (score 2):

For more complex graph queries, you may use Common Table Expressions (CTEs), standardized in SQL:99 and supported in MySQL since 8.0.1 [(reference)](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-labs-recursive-common-table-expressions-in-mysql-ctes/)

But as others pointed out, for the query you're interested in, a simple `NOT EXISTS` subquery or equivalent is enough. Yet another equivalent to those already posted would be using the `EXCEPT` set operation:

```
SELECT id FROM nodes
EXCEPT SELECT parent FROM nodes
```

Comment: I rarely see people using EXCEPT/MINUS. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated subquery that checks for node where the current not is the parent. For leafs no such record can exist.

```
SELECT *
       FROM nodes n1
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM nodes n2
                                WHERE n2.parent = n1.id);
```

Another option is a left join joining possible children of a node. If there's a null for an `id` of the "children's side" of the join no child exists for the current node, it's a leaf.

```
SELECT *
       FROM nodes n1
            LEFT JOIN nodes n2
                      ON n2.parent = n1.id
       WHERE n2.id IS NULL;
```

And, leaving denormalization away, I don't think there's much to change in the table's structure. Indexes could help though. One should be on `id` (but that's already the case because of the primary key constraint) and one on `parent` (but again such an index already exists because MySQL creates indexes for foreign key tuples).

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
select *
from nodes
where id not in (select parent from nodes where parent is not null)
```

Comment: this select leaves me with an empty result?

Comment: Fixed. A `WHERE` predicate needs to be added to the subquery.